# Flatten list of list into list for dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'data': [['748','','285','102','76024']]}
```

and I want to flatten the lists to look like this:

```
{'data': ['748','','285','102','76024']}
```

I have tried this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists):

```
[item for sublist in data.items() for item in sublist]
```

but it gives me:

> ['data',
> [['748',
> '',
> '285',
> '102',
> '76024',
> '88',
> '3',
> '89%831',
> '77%',
> '',
> '68%632',
> '19%177',
> '13%120']]]

Comment: `{k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the title, I noticed that you might have list of lists in each item in your dictionary. Using `itertools.chain()` you can merge multiple lists into one:

```py
import itertools
data = {'data': [['748','','285','102','76024']]}
data1 = {'data': [['748','','285','102','76024'], ['12', '13', '14']]}

output = {k: list(itertools.chain(*v)) for k,v in data.items()}   
output1 = {k: list(itertools.chain(*v)) for k,v in data1.items()}
```

Output:

```py
# Output
{'data': ['748', '', '285', '102', '76024']}

# Output1
{'data': ['748', '', '285', '102', '76024', '12', '13', '14']}
```